# Multiple evaluations in template literal... How can I improve my padding calculation for styled-components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, prettier

I'm trying to use styled components to style a button with some padding as shown below. Is there a cleaner way of returning two values using a single expression so I can clean this up?

```
export const Button = styled.button`
  padding: ${props => (props.primary ? rhythm(0.65) : rhythm(0.5))} ${props => (props.primary ? rhythm(1.6) : rhythm(1))};
`
```

Additionally, Prettier formats the previous code as follows. This is not valid css and so does not work. Is this a bug in prettier or is my code just horrible?

Broken:

```
export const Button = styled.button`
  padding: ${props => (props.primary ? rhythm(0.65) : rhythm(0.5))}
    ${props => (props.primary ? rhythm(1.6) : rhythm(1))};
`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate both values with one template string. It would be more readable to create a simple function, that generates the string:

```js
const rhythm = v => `${v}em`; // mock

const getPadding = (a, b) => `${rhythm(a)} ${rhythm(b)}`

const Button = styled.button`
  padding: ${props => (props.primary ? getPadding(0.65, 1.6) : getPadding(0.5, 1))};
`

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Button primary>Primary</Button>
    <Button>Not primary</Button>
  </div>,
  root
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/styled-components/4.4.0/styled-components.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```